# Relation between "$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$" and "$\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x)$"?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, definition

Perhaps I'm not understanding of it myself but to me there is a 'disconnect' between limit and derivative

> definition of the limit:
>
> Let a function f(x) be defined on a deleted neighborhood around x = a.
> Then we say that, $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x) = L$
>
> if for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there is some $\delta > 0$ s.t. $|f(x) - L| < \varepsilon $ whenever $0 < |x-a| < \delta$
>
> definition of derivative:
>
> $$ f'(x) = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$

My problem/question is that the definition of limit is to a function and in a derivative which has a limit built-in into it, it is to a variable, h, not related to a function. Am I wrong in this thinking? (feel free to answer in terms of analysis if necessary)

From what I understand, a limit has you take closer and closer approximations of a function around a particular value. A derivative has you take slopes whose points get closer and closer hence why the h goes to 0.

Comment: See also my comment following the answer of Alex G.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The definition of the derivative involves the limit of a *new* function, not your original function $f$. We fix a value $x$ at which we wish to compute the derivative of $f$. Then we define a new function (call it $g$ for lack of creativity):
$$
g(h) = \frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h}
$$

Now we note that $g$ is defined on a small neighborhood of $0$, and so we can consider the limit $\lim_{h \to 0} g(h)$. If this limit exists, it is, by definition, $f'(x)$.

People often leave the function $g(h)$ "anonymous" rather than giving it a name like $g(h)$, but it is understood from context that in the limit you're asking about, $x$ is fixed and $h$ is varying. This may take a bit of getting used to.

Comment: +1 : nicely phrased.  You might also mention that one of the consequences of the definition of the derivative of $f(x)$ at the point $(x = x_0)$ is that for the derivative of $f(x)$ to exist at $(x = x_0)$, the function $f(x)$ must be continuous at $(x = x_0)$.  This might not be readily apparent to the OP (i.e. original poster).  That is, in general, for a typical function $h(x)$, you can have that the $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to x_0} h(x)$ exists and equals some finite value $L$, without the function $h(x)$ actually being continuous at $(x = x_0)$.

Comment: This completely clears up my misunderstanding. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Intuitively, the limit of a function $f(x)$ at $a$ is just the value of $f$ near $a$. This is quite simple to visualize.

On the other hand, the (first) derivative of a function at $a$ is the "limit" of how fast the function changes near $a$. Graphically, it is the slope of the function.

More formally, the derivative $f'$ is the limit of the function that computes the slope of $f$. So technically it's a limit but it has a specific purpose, to compute a slope.